# Javascript - setAttribute - onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I am newbie in js. I have a problem with one issue.
I want to set use my function on my parahraph to set the attribiutes..

```
<body>
<p id=1>Paragraph 1</p>
<p id=2>Paragraph 2</p>
<p id=3>Paragraph 3</p>
</body>

<script>
function myFunction(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.color = "green";
}
initAll();
function initAll() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    var n;
    for (n = 0; n < elements.length; ++n) {
        elements[n].setAttribute("onclick", "myFunction(%d)", n);
    }

}
</script>
```

In the output I have something like that:
[image: output]

I can't provide the references of variable n.

Maybe is there better way to set the attribiutes?

Comment: Why do you expect sprintf-like format strings to work here...? It's unclear to my how you got this idea, I don't see any evidence of it ever being supported by `setAttribute`. Please refer to the docs of each function/method you use as to how it works (and how it doesn't). I think `console` logging functions are the only methods like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want to attach an event listener( for click event ) on each `p` element and execute that function when clicking on the elements.

To attach an event listnener on an element you can use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

To get the ID and pass it as a param to your function you can use [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

You can also use `const` and `let` instead of `var`. Read here -> [var vs let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var) or here [var let const](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/)

```js
function myFunction(id) {

    document.getElementById(id).style.color = "green";
}

function initAll() {
    const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

    for (let n = 0; n < elements.length; ++n) {
        const elementId = elements[n].getAttribute("id")
        elements[n].addEventListener("click", function(){
            myFunction(elementId)
        });
    }
}
initAll()
```

```html
<p id=1>Paragraph 1</p>
<p id=2>Paragraph 2</p>
<p id=3>Paragraph 3</p>
```

Comment: .getAttribute - I just needed it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

1- HTML `ID`s can't start with a numbers.

```
<p id=myID1>Paragraph 1</p>
```

2- Concatenate the string with `n`

```
"" + (n+1) + ""
```

3- Since the `ID` is a `string`, you have to close it inside single quotes

```
"myFunction('myID" + (n+1) + "')"
```

```js
function myFunction(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.color = "green";
}

function initAll() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
  var n;
  for (n = 0; n < elements.length; ++n) {
    elements[n].setAttribute("onclick", "myFunction('myID" + (n+1) + "')");
  }
}

initAll();
```

```html
<body>
  <p id=myID1>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p id=myID2>Paragraph 2</p>
  <p id=myID3>Paragraph 3</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Why can't ID's start with numbers ? Why concatenate when you can use template strings ?

Comment: @MihaiT ID can't start with numbers in HTML4, but actually checking in HTML5 is no longer a problem. And why not a concatenated string, it's a preference.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set the `onclick` attribute to your paragraph elements and assign them to your `myFunction`.

Since your ids start from `1`, you've to write `(n + 1)` inside the body of `for` loop
(loop variable `n` starts from `0`)

In Javascript, there are no formatting specifiers (`%d`) available like in `C`. So you just do string concatenation using the `+` operator.

So, the line should be,

```js
for (var n = 0; n < elements.length; ++n) {
   var index = n + 1;
   elements[n].setAttribute("onclick", "myFunction(" + index + ")");
}
```

It'll work fine now.

But this is not a way people use to add event listeners in JavaScript. I recommend checking out `forEach` and `addEventListener` methods in MDN.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach